# How do I use copyField (solr4) to create a field that's searchable across multiple fields?

Tags: solr, solr4

I'm trying to configure copyField, but the documentation is pretty light on syntax examples.

This is what I tried to do, but the "all" field has no documents after re-importing all my data:

```
   <field name="all" type="text_en_splitting" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true" termVectors="true" version="1.5" />
   <copyField source="id" dest="all"/>
   <copyField source="item_name" dest="all"/>
   <copyField source="item_brand" dest="all"/>
   <copyField source="short_description" dest="all"/>
   <copyField source="long_description" dest="all"/>
   <copyField source="catalog_names" dest="all"/>
   <copyField source="categories" dest="all"/>
   <copyField source="keywords" dest="all"/>
   <copyField source="attributes" dest="all"/>
```

All I really need is this:

I have documents with all of these fields defined (id, item_name, short/long description, etc).

I want to search on most of the fields, but not store the values (I just return the document ID).

So:

- Do I need to define a field for each of these attributes (item_name, short/long desc., etc.)?
- Should I be copying them all into one field so I can search across all those fields? This is necessary right?
- Is there a way that I should just import all of these fields into one solr field? How should my schema.xml look?

I don't have any searches that look at one particular fields at this time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Do I need to define a field for each of these attributes*
You need to define all the fields any way if you want to retrieve their values.

*Should I be copying them all into one field so I can search across all those fields? This is necessary right?*
You would need to copy them to a single field and search over that field.

*Is there a way that I should just import all of these fields into one solr field? How should my schema.xml look?*
you can define dynamic fields and have a single copyfield to copy them to a single field

Answer (score 0):

It seems that my biggest problem in copyField was that I needed to drop and re-load the index to enable it. It was sufficient to add a doc that replaces an existing doc.

Comment: Yes, almost any time you make changes to the schema.xml file, the changes will not be reflected in the indexed documents until the documents are reloaded.